# Need variable to = data from file

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I have a file called `raw_info` and I want a variable to point to this file so that when I type a command in a script, it'll know to look in `raw_info`. For this assignment I've been asked to, at the top of my script, define the variable `starting_info` to have the value of `raw_info`

I tried that at the beginning of my script:

```bash
#Homework Week X

name=First\ Last
echo $name
date
starting_info=raw_info
cut -f3 -d, starting_info > first
cut -f2 -d, starting_info > last
cut -f1 -d, starting_info > id
#(pretend the rest of my script is here)
```

But I get the error message:

`cut: starting_info: No such file or directory`

Comment: When you want to get the value of a variable you must prefix it with: `$`. For example `cut -f3 -d, $starting_info > first`

Comment: Suggest you don't use `id` as a filename, since it is also the name of a system provided command.

Comment: Thank you all! I'll try these tonight

Comment: You all are amazing. Thank you again, that worked! Again, I just need a lot of reps so I'll be asking y'all for lots of help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: @JeremyBoden why would that be a problem? Unless the file is placed in a directory that is in the user's `$PATH` , _and_ is made executable, _and_ the directory comes first in `$PATH`, before the standard `/sbin/` or `/bin`, there will be no issue. Since this is just a simple text file created by redirection, you can call it anything you want with no issue.

Comment: It's true that there wouldn't be any issue, but more generally, in a more complicated script a future reader might struggle to understand the reasons for redirections to filenames which are the same as system command names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

```
#!/bin/bash
#Homework Week X

name="First Last"
echo "$name" # always quote variables
date
starting_info=raw_info # now starting_info is a variable
# then you need $ sigil to call it:
cut -f3 -d, "$starting_info" > first
cut -f2 -d, "$starting_info" > last
cut -f1 -d, "$starting_info" > id
#(pretend the rest of my script is here)
```